# Have a clickable page

Tags: c#, xaml, resize, textblock, viewbox

What I want is to have a page with a Textblock in the middle. Also I want the page to be clickable (as in you should be able to click anywhere on the entire page and the function will be called).

What I've tried is to have the TextBlock in a Viewbox and to set stretch to full, but that made the textblock text out of proportion. And if I set it to Uniform it only takes up however much space it needs. So either way it doesn't work.

Also the textblock needs to automatically resize itself when the page gets bigger / smaller (i.e. set Height and Width to "Auto"), I've tried a lot and nothing works, so any help is appreciated. Below is what I currently have.

```
<Viewbox x:Name="MainViewbox" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1, 1, 1, 1">
    <TextBlock x:Name="MainTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Text="6" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Foreground="LightSkyBlue"/>
</Viewbox>
```

This Almost works but I can only click on the six, not on the whole screen.

Anyway thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

All I had to do was add a pointerReleased event handler to the page, rather than the Viewbox